# How to stop duplicating a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, dom, initialization, progress-bar

The problem that I have over here is that whenever I update the progressbar value with a pos+1, it keeps on creating a new bar while adding the progress to the original progress bar.  How do I solve the duplicate problem?

Here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_progress_create) to test my code.

```
var progbar = document.createElement("PROGRESS");
progbar.id = 'progress';
progbar.setAttribute("value", "1");
progbar.setAttribute("max", "10");
document.getElementById("status").appendChild(progbar);
document.getElementById("progress").value = (pos+1);
```

Comment: There is nothing that looks particulary wrong in the code, perhaps you're calling this piece of code multiple times or included the javascript file twice in your document. You should check all these as well and maybe setup a jsfiddle for us with your problem so that we can check your circumstances ;)

Answer (score 2):

You example is given more information about the problem you are dealing with.

Basically, you have a single script to create a progressbar and to update the same progressbar.  If you want to do both tasks in the same script, you need to do a check to see if the progress bar is already in your page before creating it.

```
function myFunction(){
    //Check if the progress is already in the page to avoid creating it more than once
    if (!document.getElementById("progress")){
      var x = document.createElement("PROGRESS");

      x.setAttribute("id", "progress");
      x.setAttribute("value", "22");
      x.setAttribute("max", "100");
      document.body.appendChild(x);
    }

    //Not sure where the pos value was taken from... I assumed you wanted to increase the progressbar value by 1
    document.getElementById("progress").value++;
}
```